# sed replace whole line by line number - chaining commands

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I need to replace a line in a file and struggling with it. Firstly I need to find a string in the file, store this line number as a variable and then replace the whole line using the variable with a new string.

I have tried a few variations of sed and currently the code I have is as follows:

```
line=$(grep -n "latitude" /tmp/system.cfg |cut -f1 -d:); 
sed "{$line}s/.*/system.latitude=1.888888/" /tmp/system.cfg ;
```

I have run the first command and successfully set `line`. When echoing $line I get 176. However, the sed command does not seem to be replacing the line regardless of if I use the variable or manually place the 176 like so

```
sed "176s/.*/system.latitude=1.888888/" /tmp/system.cfg ;
```

I have also tried the following which seems to write the line to the file, but it adds the line, rather than overwriting the existing line:

```
sed -i  $line'i'"system.latitude=1.76011"  /tmp/system.cfg;
line=$(grep -n "latitude" /tmp/system.cfg |cut -f1 -d:);
```

I have also tried using single and double quotes to no avail. Can someone point me in the direction of where I am going wrong.

Comment: Why havn't you used `-i` for the other sed commands like `sed -i "176s/.*/system.latitude=1.888888/" /tmp/system.cfg ;`

Comment: To be honest I have used sed like once before and not too familiar. I am just grabbing snippets form here there and everywhere and testing them. I'm more PHP than bash.

Comment: So does using `-i` option for the other command do the trick?

Comment: Is the line which needs substituting known to be after the line which contains the line number?

Comment: @TomFenech the line number represents the line which needs to be substituted

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I will hang my head in shame, yes adding the `-i` attribute has gotten me further towards my goal.

Comment: This is what is known as an XY problem. You have decided upon a process (find the line, store to a variable, etc.) and asked how to do that, rather than simply asking "how do I replace the whole line that matches a pattern". Well done to Kent for getting to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I understood you right, you can just save the `grep|cut`, your requirement could be done in one shot with (gnu) sed:

```
sed -i '/latitude/s/.*/system.latitude=1.888888/' /tmp/system.cfg
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. Why I thought I needed the line number first is beyond me, I'm sure there was some logic there somewhere, but anyway good to learn these things.

Comment: Why not just `sed -i 's/.*latitude.*/system.latitude=1.888888/' /tmp/system.cfg` or even `sed -i 's/.*\(latitude\).*/system.\1=1.888888/' /tmp/system.cfg`.

Answer (score 1):

Kent was absolutely correct when he mentioned about cutting the grep out of the equation completely. For anyone interested here is the final code using my method:

```
line=$(grep -n "latitude" /tmp/system.cfg |cut -f1 -d:); 
sed -i "${line}s/.*/system.latitude=1.999/" /tmp/system.cfg;
```

But I will be going with Kent's answer for the final implementation.

This is one of those issues where you commit to a process and complicate matters further as pointed out by Tom:

> This is what is known as an XY problem. You have decided upon a process (find the line, store to a variable, etc.) and asked how to do that, rather than simply asking "how do I replace the whole line that matches a pattern". Well done to Kent for getting to the bottom of it. –  Tom Fenech